# VBA Checking if clipboard is from within document or from somewhere else

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, protected

I have protected sheet in word with enforced style lock. I want to make a macro that allows pasting within document with orginal formating and allows only to paste text from other sources.

I want to make it looks like:

```
Public Sub Pasting()


If "pasting within document = true" Then
Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
aDoc.Unprotect
Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
aDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=True
Else
Selection.Paste 'it will remove formating anyway because of file being protected
End If


End Sub
```

I dont know how to deal with it and how design conditional statement.
Please help, thanks : )

Comment: Why would you not simply use the options already built into Word to set the paste format depending on the source? _File>Options>Advanced>Cut, copy and paste_.

Comment: It does not work in protected file. I want to make file that i can edit only by macros (formatting)and not let someone break  formatting by pasting from another source. But i want to let copy-paste inside formatted by macros text.

Comment: When you say "paste from document" do you mean the same document (where the checking code exists), or something else than Word?

Comment: I mean to allow pasting with formatting from current document only to the same document. And disable formatting when im pasting from another document and another program. I want to make document where you cannot use formatting from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like below, but it allows to paste formatting from another word documents as well. I want to avoid it - allow only to paste formatting only from current document.
Maybe someone know how to modify it?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardOwner Lib "user32" () As Long
Public a As Long
Sub Document_open()
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy
a = GetClipboardOwner
End Sub


'and
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardOwner Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Sub Pasting()

If GetClipboardOwner = ThisDocument.a Then
    Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
    aDoc.Unprotect
    Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    aDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=True
Else
Selection.Paste
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: This should not have been posted as an answer. It is merely an expansion of your question. There is an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68146660/edit) link below the question that you should use to add further detail.

Comment: Thx I will do this next time.